# @LastModifiedDate working as intended locally, but not once the code gets deployed to a test server

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

The code itself is exactly the same between the two environments. Locally, both @CreatedDate and @LastModifiedDate annotations work just fine, but only @CreatedDate works in the test server. The servers aren't exactly in parity for reasons I can't go into, but from the configurations I can see, I don't see anything that I think would affect only @LastModifiedDate functionality. Is there some parameter that would do that?

I realize this is vague, but the problem may be in any number of areas and the code is the same so snippets aren't useful.

Comment: I suggest remote debugging your app on test server to see what is the problem.

Comment: Maybe the server's time zone is in UTC

Comment: @VinayPandey Could that cause it to not update? The problem isn't that it's updating to an incorrect time, it just isn't updating period. It gets set during entity creation then never changes.